# Django calculate Avg for a computed field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model as below.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):

    time1 = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    time2 = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    @property
    def time_diff(self):
        return time2.total_seconds() - time1.total_seconds()
```

I need to get the average of the (time2 - time1) in seconds for a list of records, if both values are not null.

```
time_avg = transactions.aggregate(total=Avg('time_diff',field='time_diff'))
```

This gives an error saying 'time_diff' is not a valid field. I want to keep this column as a derived property. Not a stored column.

Comment: can you add what have you tried and what is your problem?

Comment: thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: you can't filter a property in your queryset, you need to use the F() function to do that. btw that is your backend db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find difference and then take avarage. You can use django `F` function for this like this.

```
from django.db.models import F    
result = Transaction.objects.filter('your_filter_here').annotate(time_diff=F('time1')-F('time2')).aggregate(Avg('time_diff'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
time_avg = transactions.aggregate(Avg('time_diff')).values()
```